# RGeo PostGIS multi-table query

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgis, rgeo

The following query runs fine as raw sql, but because it hits 2 models, I'm not sure how construct it in active record...

```
sql =  "SELECT spots.*
              FROM spots, areas 
              WHERE areas.area = '#{@area.area}'
              AND shape && lonlat
              AND ST_Contains(shape,lonlat);"
```

How could I go about constructing this? It's not a join so...

Thanks!

Comment: I don't do Ruby so can't comment on that, but you don't need the &&. This is already implied in ST_Contains, which first checks bounding box containment.

Comment: It is a join, just an implicit one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate this same SQL this way:

```
Spot.from("spots, areas")
    .where("areas.area = ?",@area.area)
    .where("shape && lonlat")
    .where("ST_Contains(shape,lonlat)")
```

But this way you aren't using what ActiveRecord have best like eager loads and relationships.
To get the same result you could do this:

In models:

```
Spot < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :area
end

Area < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And the query:

```
Spot.joins(:area).where(areas: {area: @area.area})
```